# xStream changes order of objects in write/readObject with JSON serialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, xstream

We use XStream to serialize objects to JSON and vice versa.

We init xStream like this

`XStream xStream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver(new Configuration(), false));
xStream.ignoreUnknownElements();
xStream.setMode(XStream.XPATH_RELATIVE_REFERENCES);`

We have test class

```
public static class TestWOWithBI implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4720678317857471031L;

    private transient String customerNickname;
    private transient String customerUuid;
    private transient BigInteger discussionId;
    private transient String message;

    public TestWOWithBI(String customerNickname, String customerUuid, BigInteger discussionId, String message){
        this.customerNickname = customerNickname;
        this.customerUuid = customerUuid;
        this.discussionId = discussionId;
        this.message = message;
    }

    private final void writeObject(final ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        out.defaultWriteObject();
        out.writeObject(customerNickname);
        out.writeObject(customerUuid);
        out.writeObject(discussionId);
        out.writeObject(message);
    }

    private final void readObject(final ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        in.defaultReadObject();
        customerNickname = (String) in.readObject();
        customerUuid = (String) in.readObject();
        discussionId = (BigInteger) in.readObject();
        message = (String) in.readObject();
    }
}
```

After serialization it looks like this:

> {
>       "somethere.ObjectToJSONSerializerTest$TestWOWithBI": {
>           "@serialization": "custom",
>           "somethere.ObjectToJSONSerializerTest$TestWOWithBI": {
>               "default": "",
>               "string": ["name",
>               "uuid",
>               "message"],
>               "big-int": 1
>           }
>       }
>   }

and deserialization fails with class cast. It was on 1.3.1 and 1.4.7 versions. Looks like bug to me, but may be where is some settings?

UPD:
Seems like org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLStreamWriter.JSONPropertyObject#withProperty

```
if(old != null) {
JSONArray values;
// Convert an existing property to an array
// and append to the array
if (old instanceof JSONArray) {
    values = (JSONArray)old;
} else {
    values = new JSONArray();
    values.put(old);
}
values.put(value);

object.put(property.getKey(), values);
} else if(getSerializedAsArrays().contains(property.getKey())) {
JSONArray values = new JSONArray();
values.put(value);
object.put(property.getKey(), values);
} else {
// Add the property directly.
object.put(property.getKey(), value);
}
```

It just group elements of same type.

Comment: may solve the problem [patch](http://pastebin.com/n3qpRGHS)